# Scikit-learn version ambiguity

Tags: python, version, scikit-learn

I have anaconda 2.7 for Windows 7, 64 bit. I wanted to upgrade my scikit-learn version from 0.15 to 0.16.1 but I had some connection problems so I could not follow the guide here: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/install.html#id1 (I tried several times...) . So I used scikit-learn-0.16.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe (md5) downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn/0.16.1. 
 When I go to check the version of scikit learn in spider using the code:

```
 import sklearn
 sklearn.__version__
```

I read the exact version, that is: '0.16.1' but if I try to use:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
```

I have the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name check_arrays
```

that means that actually, it doesn't use the version 0.16.1!
So how can I solve? I tried to unistall and install again but it is the same. Since I have  network restriction I can't access to the web using the command windows.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade a package installed with anaconda with pip. Just do `conda update scikit-learn`, see the [installation docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/install.html#canopy-and-anaconda-for-all-supported-platforms)

Comment: I did but it  didn't work ( i have some restrictions). As I wrote, I read the installation docs and  finally I tried the.exe

Comment: What do you mean by restrictions, and what do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: try removing the whole folder that you installed it into and then the exe again maybe.