# Wrong scikit-learn version installed?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conda

I encountered the same

`ValueError: scoring must return a number, got [...] (<class 'numpy.core.memmap.memmap'>) instead.`

error as discussed in [Q34857870](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34857870/1257318).

Based on answers to this question, and my own research, I believe this issue to be fixed in `scikit-learn` version 0.17.1, though I'm still encountering it. Then I noticed something strange.

`conda` lists the right version.

`$ conda list scikit-learn
packages in environment: 
scikit-learn              0.17.1              np111py27_0`

My Jupyter notebook gives the right version:

`%load_ext watermark
%watermark scikit-learn
scikit-learn 0.17.1`

But I get a different version when I check the version within my code:

`import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
0.17`

I wouldn't think anything of this, except I'm still seeing a bug in 0.17 that should have been fixed in 0.17.1, so I'm wondering whether I'm using the wrong version somehow.

I'm wondering if it is somehow connected to [Q30666685](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666685/scikit-learn-version-ambiguity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have multiple versions of scikit learn installed. You can see where it is installed by using

```
print(sklearn.__file__)
```

and then simply delete that. In case if you are still having version troubles work within a virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks – that was very helpful. I found another installation, and got rid of it. Still seeing the bug, but at least I can verify I have the most up-to-date version of scikit-learn.